# Realm-java and many-to-many relations

Tags: java, android, realm

How can I create a many-to-many relationships using Realm database on Android? For example, I need two types of objects: PostObject and HashTagObject, linked one to the other, something like this.

```
public class PostObject extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String text;
    private RealmList<HashTagObject> hashtags;
}

public class HashTagObject extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String tag;
    private RealmList<PostObject> posts;
}
```

I want to be able to create a post and to attach a hashtag to it, while also being able to get the posts that use the hashtag. Is that the correct implementation? How do I create a hashtag or use the existing one, if I already have it?

When I create new post I do:

```
realm.beginTransaction();

PostObject post = realm.createObject(PostObject.class);
post.setText("New post");

HashTagObject tag = realm.createObject(HashTagObject.class);
tag.setTag("tag");
tag.getPosts().add(post);

post.getTags().add(tag);    
realm.commitTransaction();
```

When I create another I do the same.

As I understand, this one will create new hashtag every time and in the end I will have two hashtag objects with the tag "tag", while I want to have only the one hashtag "tag".

Comment: Why will you have two hashtag objects? Here, if you call `realm.createObject(HashTagObject.class)` only once, only one `HashTagObject` will be created. And you didn't set the right primary key, when you call it second time, an exception will be thrown because of it is trying to use a duplicated PK 0 which is the default value.

Comment: I mean if i will try to createObject(HashTagObject.class) with the same tag next time, when I want to add this specific existing tag to my post, it will create the duplicate I dont need. One solution is to look in db for this tag, and if there is none, create one and add to the post, if there is - get it and add.

Comment: Then the simplest solution is using the `tag` as the `@PrimaryKey`. Then create it like this `HashTagObject hto = new HashTagObject(); hto.setTag("tag"); hto = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(hto);` This will create a standalone `RealmObject` first, `copyToRealmOrUpdate` will try to update the object with same PK in Realm and return the managed `RealmObject`. No more duplicate object!